# Mercedes veto Exhaust

Tags: exhaust, mercedes-benz, smell

Just got a new exhaust fitted, the part that goes from the front wheel area all the way to the back. And NOW there is a smell of exhaust fumes in the veacle, that seams to be coming from the vents. Also the exhaust makes a noise every so often when the back hanging bolt is hitting the body of the car. Could the fumes be from the badly fitted exhaust? Or most likely something else?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please confirm if you installed a new exhaust gasket that goes between the engine and the exhaust headers (the front most part of the exhaust)

Comment: Don't think so, if wasn't on the bill. I think the part from the engine to the underneath of the car is the only part not changed.